# Filtering on column : Pyspark

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I will filter a column on dataframe for to have only the number (digit code).

| main_column |
| --- |
| HKA1774348 |
| null |
| 774970331205 |
| 160-27601033 |
| SGSIN/62/898805 |
| null |
| LOCAL |
| 217-29062806 |
| null |
| 176-07027893 |
| 724-22100374 |
| 297-00371663 |
| 217-11580074 |

I obtain this column

| main_column |
| --- |
| 774970331205 |
| 160-27601033 |
| 217-29062806 |
| 176-07027893 |
| 724-22100374 |
| 297-00371663 |
| 217-11580074 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [rlike](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python//reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.Column.rlike.html) with an regexp that only includes digits and a hyphen:

```python
df.where(df['main_column'].rlike('^[0-9\-]+$')).show()
```

Output:

```
+------------+
| main_column|
+------------+
|774970331205|
|160-27601033|
|217-29062806|
|176-07027893|
|724-22100374|
|297-00371663|
|217-11580074|
+------------+
```

Comment: I would like to use "is.disgit() in pyspark